# Exporting from sharepoint 2010 wiki to pdf

Tags: sharepoint-server

I'm new at Sharepoint 2010 server. For now, working on sharepoint wiki. I've been searching for hours to find a solution about exporting wiki page to pdf.

For example. I have some stuff in my wiki page and i have a custom template for a document which have to be saved in pdf.

Is there a manual or guide how to create that option, save wiki page into custom made template and final result would be a pdf file with my customised template and information from wiki.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the main you need to use 3rd Party tools to do this...however i did find this method...

> In our project, we use the SharePoint 2010 wiki to document our
>   solutions. We needed to export this in PDF format when releasing the
>   solution to production, so that we could pass over a formal
>   documentation set to the operations team, and not just refer to a
>   constantly changing wiki, which also had a number of pages irrelevant
>   to operations

[Export SharePoint Wiki to Word/PDF without 3rd party tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thomsven/archive/2011/09/09/export-sharepoint-wiki-to-word-pdf-without-3rd-party-tools.aspx?Redirected=true)

S

Comment: thanks! i tried but it did not give me a wanted result. have to look another way.